# Phpexcel doesn't update related data in another worksheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel 1.8 with 2 worksheets.

Worksheet number 1 is a summary page and worksheet 2 a list of articles with details and amounts.

Worksheet 1 has several references on specifics cells in worksheet 2.

When using [`insertNewRowBefore`](http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Worksheet/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#methodinsertNewRowBefore) methods in worksheet 2 to create the list of articles, the references on related cells in worksheet 1 is not updated.

Cells references are well updated in the same worksheet, but it seems that a limitation exists if cells are referenced in other worksheet.

[Documentation](http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Worksheet/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#methodinsertNewRowBefore) says that all possible related data are updated.

Is it a bug? A limitation? Or is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPExcel confirms the limitation
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/1099